# Form creation cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am working on a project in cakephp.For the view part,I have the following snippet of code

```
echo $form->create("generals",array('action' => 'search')); 
echo $form->input("q", array('label' => 'Search for')); 
echo $form->end("Search");
```

If I am not wrong,term entered in the textbox is represented by q. how do I catch this term and use it in my search method in the generals controller.

Please let me know your views on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in Cake 1.x, your data should be available in the array `$this->data` ... if you're in Cake 2.x, you can access it through `$this->request-data` ...

If you `debug` or `print_r` or `var_dump` the array, you'll see the structure ...

For 1.x see http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

For 2.x see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html